# While Playing YouTube Video in Web Browser in WP8 audio sound remains to play for sometime in BackGround of the App

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, youtube

While Playing YouTube Video in Web Browser in WP8 and when I press Backkey in between it redirects to the required page but resumes to play audio for some time in BackGround of the App.
I am giving following link as an input to the web browser
link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/YouTube_ID";
So can anyone help me to resolve this problem, Or anyone can tell me subsequent method to play Video using youtube ID.

Comment: Did you try out the msdn sample? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Youtube-Video-Sample-f2692dc9

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Yes I tried this also, but while the video is playing and in between when I press the back-key it navigates to the page and when I try to play the second video  it gets stuck in between some blank page and nothing is displayed. I am having Video Id of the all video playlists, just need to play them using this IDs. Can you please help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube) `Youtube` class from the `Codeplex`.

For more refer this one too:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4201e160-6c72-4b2b-9ef4-a5206395c43f/how-to-play-you-tube-video-in-windows-phone-on-click-the-button?forum=wpdevelop

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have already gone through this blog, But again its not working. Then i decided to use HTML with the source embeded with the youtube link with youtube ID, its working but again when video is playing and if I press back key it takes some 6-7 secs to come back to the desired page.